# How to use multiple databases in EcomDev PHPUnit fixtures

Tags: ecomdev-phpunit, phpunit, ce-1.9.1.0

I set up unit tests for Magento 1.9.1.0 using EcomDev PHPUnit. I was able to make almost everything working properly. The only thing which I haven't figured out is how to use fixtures in multiple database setup.

There are two database resources set in `local.xml`:

- `default_setup` used by the whole codebase as default connection
- `my_extension` used by one custom extension, declared in module `config.xml`

Then I have following fixtures in `default.yaml` file:

```
aliases:        
    user: &user
        id: 1
        login: john
        password: foo
        email: john@example.com
        customer_id: 1
        firstname: John
        lastname: Doe
        customer_id: 1

tables:
    my_extension/user:
      -
        <<: *user
        id: 1

eav:
    customer:
      -
        <<: *eav_customer
        entity_id: 1
        firstname: John
        lastname: Smith
        email: example1@example.com
```

I would like to have `eav/customer` fixture added using `default_setup` resource and `my_extension/user` fixture added using `my_extension` resource.

As far as I see in `EcomDev_PHPUnit_Model_Fixture_Processor_Tables`, it always uses default resource.

For now I just configured test Magento environment to have both resources using the same database.

Do you know any elegant way to make fixtures working with different resources?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Good question but looking back at the projects I have used Ecom_Dev on I don't think that this is possible. By having the data split out as well it would look more like you are testing the infrastructure. E.g. Another DB connection can write / read.

When using unit testing and Ecom_Dev where the data is stored should not really make much of a difference, This could be covered at a higher level to ensure it works..

Comment: Thanks James, it makes sense. It looks it's not supported, however using one database for testing purposes is enough there.